# Firebase rules: where can I find the user to which a id belongs to?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a realtime firebase database and its rules include:

```
{
  "rules": {
        "people" : {
          ".read" : "auth.uid === 'AIza...'",
          ".write" : "auth.uid === 'AIza...'"
        },
  }
}
```

How can I find out to which user this id belongs to? What does this rule do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does this rule do?

It grants read and write to the `rules/people` DB node only to the user with uid (from the Authentication service) equal to `AIza...`. See the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#authentication) for more details.

> How can I find out to which user this id belongs to?

Look at the Authentication part in the console. You can search a user by uid in the Search field as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Renaud, I've looked at the Authentication part: although there are many users, the columns 'Identified' and 'Providers' are empty for all users. And 'User UID' always consists of just 4 numbers. So nothing with `AIza...`. I've also looked at "Users and Permissions" under the Realtime database. But also there, I don't see anything with `AIza...`. Should it have been there? (perhaps it's not there and the user simply doesn't exist... and that line in the Rule just doesn't work...)

Comment: Then there is indeed, in your Firebase project, a mismatch between the hard-coded value found in your rules and the users in the Auth service. I do confirm that `auth.uid` in the rules is checked against the users declared in the Firebase Authentication service for the same Firebase project.